# Why doesn't my text inside a StackLayout wrap around?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I have this code that appears inside a `<TableSection>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Japanese.CategoryGroupCommentViewCell">
    <StackLayout 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Padding="20,10"
        BackgroundColor="#EAEAF1">
        <Label
            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyleStyle}"
            TextColor="#59595F" 
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
            Text="Click on the Category Groups and then select one or more Categories from the page that appears"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
```

When it displays I see the words:

> Click on the Category Groups and then select

The rest is cut off.

I also tried this and it's the same:

```
<ViewCell 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Japanese.CategoryGroupCommentViewCell">
    <Grid 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Padding="20,10"
        BackgroundColor="#EAEAF1">
        <Label
            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyleStyle}"
            TextColor="#59595F" 
            Text="Click on the Category Groups and then select one or more Categories from the page that appears"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: could you share the whole code how you set the tableview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove **Orientation** property and try it

**EDITED**

Remove **RowHeight** in your **ListView** if you put there and Add **HasUnevenRows="true"** in your **ListView**